# Strange behavior when calling WorksheetFunction.Average in VBA

Tags: excel, range, vba

I have a sub:

```
Sub TestrowSelectRetsRange()
  Dim lastrow As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim n As Integer
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim avgReturn As Long

    With Worksheets("RatiosCalc")
        For i = 354 To 1500
            'compare concatenation of columns L:Q with empty string
            If Trim(Join(Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(.Range("A" & i & ":HU" & i).Value)), "")) = "" Then
                lastrow = i
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    End With

    n = lastrow - 1
    'set range
    Set rng = Worksheets("RatiosCalc").Range("E354" & ":E" & n)
    'rng.Select
    avgReturn = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(rng)
    MsgBox avgReturn
 End Sub
```

MsgBox returns 0, while the same function called in worksheet returns a proper average value. Does anyone have an idea why? Also, it does not matter which range of values I choose, `the sub always returns 0 in MsgBox`, `and it does not matter which WorksheetFunction I choose, the return value is again 0`.

Best Regards

Comment: try to add `rng.Calculate` just before `avgReturn = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(rng)`

Comment: @simoco Nope still 0 :/

Comment: Put a stop on the 'set rng = ' line, and check what n is - make sure it's selecting what you expect.